# FOR loop and SQL query

Tags: php, sql, loops

I am doing a daily sale report which shows total sale in everyhour from 8AM to 10PM.

The hours are easy, just simply

```
for ($x = 8; $x <= 22; $x++)
```

Then the total amount will be get from SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime), SUM(TotalAmount) AS Total FROM Tickets WHERE DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime)=$x GROUP BY DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime)";
```

If that hour doesn't have any sale, the amount will be 0. So my code is:

```
<?php
include 'go.php';
for ($x = 8; $x <= 22; $x++) {
    $money =0;
    echo "['".$x.":00', ".$money."],<br>";
    $sql = "SELECT DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime), SUM(TotalAmount) AS Total FROM Tickets WHERE DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime)=$x GROUP BY DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime)";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
        if( $stmt === false) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        }
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            $money = $row['Total'];
            echo "['".$x.":00', ".$money."],<br>";
        }
    //echo $x."<br>";
} 
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>
```

But help me, the hour that has sales showed up twice (look at 13:00, 15:00 , 17:00,..)

```
['8:00', 0],
['9:00', 0],
['10:00', 0],
['11:00', 0],
['12:00', 0],
['13:00', 0],
['13:00', 22.05],
['14:00', 0],
['15:00', 0],
['15:00', 23.95],
['16:00', 0],
['17:00', 0],
['17:00', 47.45],
['18:00', 0],
['18:00', 71.50],
['19:00', 0],
['20:00', 0],
['21:00', 0],
['22:00', 0],
```

How should I change my code to get perfect result like this:

```
['8:00', 0],
['9:00', 0],
['10:00', 0],
['11:00', 0],
['12:00', 0],
['13:00', 22.05],
['14:00', 0],
['15:00', 23.95],
['16:00', 0],
['17:00', 47.45],
['18:00', 71.50],
['19:00', 0],
['20:00', 0],
['21:00', 0],
['22:00', 0],
```

Thank so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're displaying time and money twice:

Try changing your code as :

```
<?php
include 'go.php';
for ($x = 8; $x <= 22; $x++) {
    $money =0;
//Remove or comment this line 
//        echo "['".$x.":00', ".$money."],<br>";
        $sql = "SELECT DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime), SUM(TotalAmount) AS Total FROM Tickets WHERE DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime)=$x GROUP BY DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime)";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
            if( $stmt === false) {
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
            }
            while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                if ($row['Total']) {
                    $money = $row['Total'];
                }
                echo "['".$x.":00', ".$money."],<br>";
            }
        //echo $x."<br>";
    } 
    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove your first echo statement:

```
for ($x = 8; $x <= 22; $x++) {
    $money =0;
    //Remove this one
    echo "['".$x.":00', ".$money."],<br>";
...
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $money = $row['Total'];
        //Leave this one
        echo "['".$x.":00', ".$money."],<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start looping this line always print

```
echo "['".$x.":00', ".$money."],<br>";
```

No Matter query has record or not. You have to override this row when you query find some records. I'm Refining you query.

```
<?php
$i =0; $arr = array();
for ($x = 8; $x <= 22; $x++) {
    $money =0;
    $arr[$i] = "['".$x.":00', ".$money."],<br>";
    $sql = "SELECT DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime), SUM(TotalAmount) AS Total FROM Tickets WHERE DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime)=$x GROUP BY DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime)";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
        if( $stmt === false) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        }
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            $money = $row['Total'];
            $arr[$i] = "['".$x.":00', ".$money."],<br>";
        }
    //echo $x."<br>";
$i++;
} 
echo implode(" ", $arr);
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I changed `while` to `if else`
the code works well now

```
<?php
include 'go.php';
for ($x = 8; $x <= 22; $x++) {

    $sql = "SELECT DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime), SUM(TotalAmount) AS Total FROM Tickets WHERE DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime)=$x GROUP BY DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime)";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
        if( $stmt === false) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        }
        if( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            $money = $row['Total'];
            echo "['".$x.":00', ".$money."],<br>";
        }
        else 
        {
                $money =0;
    echo "['".$x.":00', ".$money."],<br>";
        }
    //echo $x."<br>";
} 
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need a condition like `if($money == 0)` and write `echo "['".$x.":00', ".$money."],<br>";` into for loop below while loop.

```
<?php
include 'go.php';
for ($x = 8; $x <= 22; $x++) {
    $money =0;    
    $sql = "SELECT DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime), SUM(TotalAmount) AS Total FROM Tickets WHERE DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime)=$x GROUP BY DATEPART(hh,LastUpdateTime)";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
        if( $stmt === false) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        }
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            $money = $row['Total'];
            echo "['".$x.":00', ".$money."],<br>";
        }
        if($money == 0)
        echo "['".$x.":00', ".$money."],<br>";
} 
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>
```